# При рестарте приложения MediaPlayer проигрывание начиналось с момента, на котором было перезагружено приложение

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

Есть сервис для проигрывания файла музыки. Как сделать, чтобы при рестарте приложения  проигрывание начиналось с момента, на котором  было перезагружено это приложение (не используя BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: А при чём тут BroadcastReceiver? По идее при проигрывании надо просто сохранять текущий прогресс (или прогресс на момент остановки воспроизведения) куда-нибудь, например в SharedPreferences, после чего при старте приложения эту информацию считывать и запускать с нужного момента.